# download https content using libcurl/openssl without deciphering it

Tags: ssl, https, libcurl

Is it possible to download HTTPS content (in a C program, preferably via libcurl/openssl) without actually deciphering it ?

I need to code download speed tests for a number of URLs some of them being HTTPS and I noticed that for HTTPS sometimes the bottleneck is the client CPU.
In other words, I need to tell that "if you had a very fast machine, you could achieve this fast download over this link for https://...".

Currently I'm using libcurl, but if there's an other framework that is able to download un-decyphered content, I don't mind spending a few hrs of coding.

thx,

Comment: The client CPU isn't a bottleneck for SSL unless you go back to about an Intel 486. SSL encryption is very fast. The limiting factor is the network.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to do with libcurl. That I can tell with certainty.

I'm not aware of any way to do it with OpenSSL either, since you pretty much has to speak SSL to get the data and to speak it you need to decrypt it.